# Counting the number of values in each interval

Tags: list-manipulation

We have

```
SeedRandom[43]; aRRay = Sort@RandomReal[1, 20]    

(*{0.042467, 0.147432, 0.196935, 0.302397, 0.303466, 0.327691, 0.35578, 
  0.469596, 0.473433, 0.473735, 0.476401, 0.542707, 0.549238, 0.756142, 
  0.760802, 0.804339, 0.825788, 0.863324, 0.890815, 0.952522}*)
```

Please assume an interval containing `0.1`. How can we calculate the numbers of elements of `aRRay` in each interval. For instants, in the above case we wish to have an array you can say `nUm[k]` which contains:

```
interval = 0.1; 
(* For: [0,0.1)*)      nUm[1] = 1;
(* For: [0.1,0.2)*)    nUm[2] = 2;
(* For: [0.2,0.3)*)    nUm[3] = 0;
(*[0.3,0.4)*)          nUm[4] = 3;
(*[0.3,0.4)*)          nUm[4] = 4;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
BinCounts[aRRay, {0, 0.4, 0.1}]
```

Comment: I was not familiar with this function. Amazing.

Comment: If we have a list: `{0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9}` Do you know how I construct another list containing pairs: `{{0,1},{0.1,2},{0.2,0},{0.3,3}....}`

Comment: I tried `Transpose` I think it works correctly!!

Answer (score 8):

```
HistogramList[aRRay, {0, .4, .1}][[2]]
```

> {1, 2, 0, 4}

This is slower  than `BinCounts` for regularly spaced bins:

```
SeedRandom[43]; aRRay = Sort@RandomReal[1, 1000000];
BinCounts[aRRay, {0, 1., .1}] // Timing
```

> {1.093812, {99869, 99884, 100051, 100351, 99540, 99971, 99695, 99930, 
>     100337, 100372}}

```
HistogramList[aRRay, {0, 1., .1}][[2]] // Timing
```

> {1.527600, {99869, 99884, 100051, 100351, 99540, 99971, 99695, 99930, 
>     100337, 100372}}

Slightly faster for irregular bins:

```
bins = Flatten[{0, Sort[RandomReal[1, 50]], 1}];
BinCounts[aRRay, {bins}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.667586

```
HistogramList[aRRay, {bins}][[2]] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.606415

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I apologise for the number of changes this post has been through.

You *can* do better than `BinCounts` and `HistogramList`, but only (it seems) if the range of elements of the list, and the bin widths are known in advance and can be hardwired (and much better if the list consists of `Integers`). But for binning lists of `Reals` where the range and bins are not always known in advance, it's probably best to stick with `HistogramList` or `BinCounts`.

If the intervals are always `0.1` and the list elements are always between 0 and 1 you can do:

```
SeedRandom[43]; aRRay = Sort@RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20];

binlist = Table[0, 10];
binlist[[#]]++ & /@ (IntegerPart[10 aRRay] + 1);
binlist


(* {1, 2, 0, 4, 4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 1} *)
```

This will also `Compile`, which can be really handy for larger lists:

```
histbins1 = Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{binlist = Table[0, 10]},
    Scan[binlist[[#]]++ &, Floor[10 list] + 1];
    binlist
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

SeedRandom[43]; aRRay = Sort@RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10000000];
First@AbsoluteTiming[res1 = BinCounts[aRRay, 0.1]]
First@AbsoluteTiming[res2 = HistogramList[aRRay, {0.1}][[2]]]
First@AbsoluteTiming[res3 = fasthist[aRRay]]
res1 == res2 == res3

(* 0.171328
   0.231146
   0.151686
   True *)
```

So there's a small speed up, but the interval and range are hardwired.

To generalise this effectively to different ranges and bin widths, it's worth noting that if the list consists of `Integer`s we can do much better than `BinCounts` or `HistogramList`, both of which seem to sacrifice speed with `Integers` for their generality:

```
inthistbins = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}, {minmax, _Integer, 1}},
   Block[{binlist, len = minmax[[2]] - minmax[[1]] + 1, 
     offset = 1 - minmax[[1]]},
    binlist = Table[0, len];
    binlist[[# + offset]]++ & /@ list;
    binlist
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

SeedRandom[43]; aRRay = RandomInteger[1000, 1000000];
First@AbsoluteTiming[res1 = Rest@HistogramList[aRRay, {1}][[2]];]
First@AbsoluteTiming[res2 = Rest@BinCounts[aRRay, {1}];]
First@AbsoluteTiming[res3 = inthistbins[aRRay, {0, 1000}];]
res1 == res2 == res3

(* 0.0589792
   0.0127482
   0.00230177
   True *)
```

So an obvious thing to try is to convert the list to `Integer`s and do an `Integer` binning function:

```
histbins2 = 
  Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}, {minmax, _Real, 1}, {nbins, _Integer, 0}},
   Block[{binlist = Table[0, nbins], 
     intlist = 
      IntegerPart[
        nbins (list - minmax[[1]])/(minmax[[2]] - minmax[[1]])] + 1},
    Scan[binlist[[#]]++ &, intlist];
    binlist
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

SeedRandom[43]; aRRay = Sort@RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10000000]
First@AbsoluteTiming[res4 = histbins2[aRRay, {0, 1}, 10]]

(* 0.184703 *)
```

Which ultimately loses out to `BinCounts` and the hardwired `histbins1`... Unless someone can give a faster way to convert `list` to `Integers` than the one I've used here.